# How to set current date on NSDatePicker object in osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to OSX App development. In one of the sample menubar Apps I did, I used an `NSDatePicker` object. But it is not displaying the current date. How can i display the current date using an `NSDatePicker` object.

Comment: check my answer and let me know whether that helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
NSdate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
datePicker.date = currentDate;
```

??

this is the same as

```
NSdate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
[datePicker setDate:currentDate]
```

The main difference is that if `currentDate` is not equal to nil in your code, the datePicker's date does not get set!!

Comment: if still your error persists, this will help you https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=hp&tok=5QkqrhPX6r4zyyHVzWbnDw&pq=google&cp=47&gs_id=i&xhr=t&q=no+visible+%40interface+for+declares+the+selector&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=no+visible+%40interface+for+declares+the+selector&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk&fp=aaf6447fe4e1119c&bpcl=40096503&biw=1023&bih=630

Answer (score 1):

**set current system time to Datepicker**

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtStartTime: NSDatePicker!
```

swift

```
let now = Date()
txtStartTime.dateValue = now
```

Answer (score 0):

As of OSX 10.4, the way to do this is

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
[datePicker setDateValue:currentDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set date to date picker in `Swift 3.2`like,

```
self.datePicker.dateValue = NSDate() as Date
```